# For a layover in Munich, Germany on a flight from USA to Split, Croatia is 45 minutes enough and will Customs clearance take place in Split?

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, airports, short-connections, muc

We arrive from the US in Munich on June 5 in the morning. In Munich, we only have 45 minutes to catch our flight to Split, Croatia.

1. Is this enough time to make the flight?
2. Customs will be in Split, correct?

Comment: Munich is fast, but that's a pretty short time. the three standard questions:   (1) what is the two airlines involved?  (2) what time of day exactly?  (3) did you **book the tickets together**, from one airline (or one web site), or did you book them separately?

Comment: With regard to 2, Munich is like almost all Schengen airports in that it supports sterile international transit. If you arrive from a non-Schengen airport and transfer to a flight bound for another non-Schengen destination, you will not pass through immigration or customs controls (unless you need to retrieve your checked baggage and recheck it).

Answer (score 2):

Usually Munich guarantee a fast connection . If you reserved your ticket in the same PNR probably means that the minimum connection time is enough.